# Design pattern to implement Locking in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

My code looks something like :

```
private string TryOperation(Some parameters)
{
    using (var guard = new OperationGuardWithCleanup(params)) // Aquire lock
    {
        if (guard.TryStartOperation())
        {
            Operation(otherParams); // Actual operation method
            return "Success"
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to provide implementation the functionality that could take arbitrary "Operation". Is there a recommended design pattern for such utility.

Comment: An Action or Func sounds appropriate, what type is otherParams and what is the scope?

Comment: The parameters of the various methods replacing "Operation" can be different.

Comment: I am on mobile right now but you can read up on Action and Func and I can post a code sample in the morning if you still need it.

Comment: Thanks @ShaneRay I got the similar response from others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then using a delegate (similar to a function pointer in C++) would likely meet your needs.

The "Action" type can be a good choice of delegates.

```
private string TryOperation(Some parameters, Action<OtherParamsType> operation)
{
    using (var guard = new OperationGuardWithCleanup(params))
    {
        if (guard.TryStartOperation())
        {
            operation(otherParams); // Actual operation method
            return "Success"
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one simplistic way you could implement it, which you should test and harden for your own purposes. You should think about what you are trying to achieve because this will synchronize all operations across your process which might not be what you want.

```
private string TryOperation(Action operation)
{
    using (var guard = new OperationGuardWithCleanup())
    {
        if (guard.TryStartOperation())
        {
            operation();
            return "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
}

public class OperationGuardWithCleanup : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposedValue = false;
    private static readonly object _operationLock = new object();

    public OperationGuardWithCleanup()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_operationLock);
    }

    public bool TryStartOperation()
    {
        // ?
        return true;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_operationLock);
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing right now. The only thing missing was the use of Action as parameter for the operation.